# How to count nan values in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

What is the best way to account for (not a number) nan values in a pandas DataFrame?

The following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dfd = pd.DataFrame([1, np.nan, 3, 3, 3, np.nan], columns=['a'])
dfv = dfd.a.value_counts().sort_index()
print("nan: %d" % dfv[np.nan].sum())
print("1: %d" % dfv[1].sum())
print("3: %d" % dfv[3].sum())
print("total: %d" % dfv[:].sum())
```

Outputs:

```
nan: 0
1: 1
3: 3
total: 4
```

While the desired output is:

```
nan: 2
1: 1
3: 3
total: 6
```

I am using pandas 0.17 with Python 3.5.0 with Anaconda 2.4.0.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to count only NaN values in column `'a'` of a DataFrame `df`, use:

```
len(df) - df['a'].count()
```

Here `count()` tells us the number of non-NaN values, and this is subtracted from the total number of values (given by `len(df)`).

To count NaN values in *every* column of `df`, use:

```
len(df) - df.count()
```

---

If you want to use `value_counts`, tell it *not* to drop NaN values by setting `dropna=False` (added in [0.14.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0141-enhancements)):

```
dfv = dfd['a'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

This allows the missing values in the column to be counted too:

```
 3     3
NaN    2
 1     1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

The rest of your code should then work as you expect (note that it's not necessary to call `sum`; just `print("nan: %d" % dfv[np.nan])` suffices).

Comment: And after using the method above

    dfv.values.sum()

Counts all the values, i.e.

    6

Thanks. ;)

Comment: No problem! Yep, that works. In fact, you could just write `dfv.sum()` to count all the values. Or even more efficiently, just check `len(dfd)`.

Answer (score 33):

To count just null values, you can use [`isnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

```
In [11]:
dfd.isnull().sum()

Out[11]:
a    2
dtype: int64
```

Here `a` is the column name, and there are 2 occurrences of the null value in the column.

Comment: this is the easier approach

Answer (score 4):

A good clean way to count all NaN's in all columns of your dataframe would be ...

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan], 'b':[np.nan,1,np.nan]})
print(df.isna().sum().sum())
```

Using a single sum, you get the count of NaN's for each column. The second sum, sums those column sums.

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me best!

If you wanna get a simple summary use (great for data science to count missing values and their type):

```
df.info(verbose=True, null_counts=True)
```

Or another cool one is:

```
df['<column_name>'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1, 2, np.nan],
   ...:                    'b': [2, 2, np.nan, 1, np.nan],
   ...:                    'c': [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 3, np.nan]})
```

This is the df:

```
    a    b    c
0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  2.0  2.0  3.0
2  1.0  NaN  NaN
3  2.0  1.0  3.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Run Info:

```
df.info(verbose=True, null_counts=True)
   ...:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    4 non-null float64
b    3 non-null float64
c    2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
```

So you see for C you get, out of 5 rows 2 non-nulls, b/c you have null at rows: [0,2,4]

And this is what you get using value_counts for each column:

```
In [17]: df['a'].value_counts(dropna=False)
Out[17]:
 2.0    2
 1.0    2
NaN     1
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [18]: df['b'].value_counts(dropna=False)
Out[18]:
NaN     2
 2.0    2
 1.0    1
Name: b, dtype: int64

In [19]: df['c'].value_counts(dropna=False)
Out[19]:
NaN     3
 3.0    2
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `null_counts` is deprecated, rather use `show_counts`.

Answer (score 2):

if you only want the summary of null value for each column, using the following code
    `df.isnull().sum()`
if you want to know how many null values in the data frame using following code
   `df.isnull().sum().sum() # calculate total`

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to count **all** the nans in a df:

`num_nans = df.size - df.count().sum()`

Timings:

```
import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_scale = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, np.nan, 100, 63], [2, np.nan, 101, 63], [2, 12, 102, 63],
     [2, 14, 102, 63], [2, 14, 102, 64], [1, np.nan, 200, 63]] * df_scale,
    columns=['group', 'value', 'value2', 'dummy'])

repeat = 3
numbers = 100

setup = """import pandas as pd
from __main__ import df
"""

def timer(statement, _setup=None):
    print (min(
        timeit.Timer(statement, setup=_setup or setup).repeat(
            repeat, numbers)))

timer('df.size - df.count().sum()')
timer('df.isna().sum().sum()')
timer('df.isnull().sum().sum()')
```

prints:

```
3.998805362999999
3.7503365439999996
3.689461442999999
```

so pretty much equivalent