# to_csv is missing out 'NA' values

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a categorical column like this:

```
0-20      6988298  
20-40     2397062  
40-60      586665  
NA          26071  
60-80        3255  
80-100          7  
Name: CNT_INSTALMENT_BKT, dtype: int64
```

I changed the datatype to 'category'. Then I tried to write the df to a csv file using to_csv, but it is missing out the values having 'NA'. 
I changed the datatype of the column to 'object', but still facing the same issue. This is my code:

```
newdf.to_csv(r'D:\blah.csv',index=False)
```

After writing to a new file, it is giving me this output:

```
0-20      6988298  
20-40     2397062  
40-60      586665  
60-80        3255  
80-100          7  
Name: CNT_INSTALMENT_BKT, dtype: int64
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save pandas dataframe but conserving NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405994/save-pandas-dataframe-but-conserving-na-values)

Comment: I tried it. It is working i guess..I am actually not able to validate. Because when I am using df.value_counts(), it is giving an output like this :   Series([], Name: CNT_INSTALMENT_BKT, dtype: int64)

Comment: For further help, provide [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But, [also see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537048/how-to-count-nan-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe).